# Start Scrapyd as service

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapyd

1. I would like to start scrapyd as service but when I start `scrapyd`,
   if I close the SSH session the service scrapyd close automatically.
2. When I try to start as service like this I have an error :

   ```
   root@vps:~# service scrapyd start
   scrapyd: Failed to start scrapyd.service: Unit scrapyd.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
   ```
3. And when i try to start `daemon scrapyd` the CURL request return :

   ```
   {"status": "error", "message": "Use \"scrapy\" to see available commands", "node_name": "vps"}
   ```

Can someone help me to start my scrapyd as service please !

Comment: Here you can take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51319103/5957834 . It is good work around.

Answer (score 0):

```
daemon --chdir=/home/Crawler scrapyd
```

I need to set the `--chdir` to load the service on the Scrapy folder !

Answer (score 0):

I could not get my scrapyd start through **/etc/rc.local** or **crontab** so I found a work around. I am sure there will be a better way but for mean time this worked for me.

I created a python file `start.py`.

```
import os

os.system('/usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/scrapyd > /home/ubuntu/scrapy.log &')
```

And simply call the python file `start.py` through crontab.

Add this to crintab file by `cronat -e`.

```
@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/start.py
```

Basically what I did is execute the scrapy through shell by calling the python filr through crontab.

If anyone finds something better please comment.