# Scrapyd not starting at boot-up - Ubuntu 14

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have [Scrapyd](https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) installed on server.

I want it to start whenever my server restarts.

I created job here `/etc/init/myjob.conf` with following contents

```
description     "my job"
start on startup
task
cd /var/www/scrapers &&  scrapyd >& /dev/null &
```

I also tried to put following command in `crontab -e`

`@reboot cd /var/www/scrapers &&  scrapyd >& /dev/null &`

Both of them did not work.

I checked cronlogs using `grep CRON /var/log/syslog` and here I see command ran but Scrapyd did not start

```
Mar 30 13:33:28 mani CRON[446]: (root) CMD (cd /var/www/scrapers && scrapyd >& /dev/null &)
```

As you can see that command ran as ROOT user.

If I manually run that command in terminal it works!

**PS:**

I changed command to

`@reboot cd /var/www/scrapers && scrapyd >> /var/www/log.txt`

and log file is created but its empty!

Answer (score 0):

You must try to start process manually, and see what happens. The line:

```
cd /var/www/scrapers &&  scrapyd
```

makes sense if: 1) directory /var/www/scrapers do exist 2) scrapyd is a binary that exists in that directory, and PATH environment variable includes actual directory ("." wildcard).

Maybe you could try:

```
cd /var/www/scrapers &&  ./scrapyd
```

without redirect standar output to /dev/null, to see what happens. Always try manual before use cron.

Answer (score 0):

I could not get my scrapyd start through **/etc/rc.local** or **crontab** so I found a work around. I am sure there will be a better way but for mean time this worked for me.

I created a python file `start.py`.

```
import os

os.system('/usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.local/bin/scrapyd > /home/ubuntu/scrapy.log &')
```

And simply call the python file `start.py` through crontab.

Add this to crintab file by `cronat -e`.

```
@reboot /usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/start.py
```

Basically what I did is execute the scrapy through shell by calling the python filr through crontab.